# How to prepare a 2x2 Confusion matrix for binary classifier

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, confusion-matrix

Problem statement: Evaluate a binary classifier. There are 50 positive outcomes in the test data, and 100 observations. Using a 50% threshold, the classifier predicts 40 positive outcomes, of which 10 are incorrect. Calculate classifier’s Precision and Recall on the test sample?

My tried solution: I have calculated Precision as : P = TP / TP + FP => P = 40 / 40 + 10 => P = 0.8 And, same Recall. But, I am not sure its correct as F1 score options are not matching with mine.

So, I need to build a correct 2x2 Confusion matrix.

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicates.

Comment: My sincere apologies for this. I was busy with some other project and came back today again for my previous problem.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of positive outcomes in the data is:
P = 50

The number of negative outcomes in the data is:
N = 50

The number of observations predicted as positive that are really positive is:
TP = 30

The number of observations predicted as positive which in reality are negative is:
FP = 10

Sensitivity = Recall = True Positive Rate = TP/P = 30/50 = 0.6

Precision = PPV = TP/P* = 30/40 = 0.75

F1 score = harmonic mean precision and sensitivity =
$\dfrac{2*\text{prec}*\text{sens}}{\text{prec}+\text{sens}} = \dfrac{2*0.75*0.6}{0.75+0.6} = 0.66$

Comment: Thanks for this. It has cleared my concepts as well.
I am really grateful to the way you explained the solution of the problem.